# How to append “%” symbol?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure which is returning a integer value, but at the time of print I want to print “%” symbol.

```
declare @avg int
exec example @avg output
select @avg
```

It is giving only number like 80. But I want 80%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since @avg is declared as int, you have to cast it before appending a character.

```
SELECT cast(@avg as varchar(5)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem correct to try to solve this by modifying your Stored Procedure. Isn't there any way in which you can add the % symbol in the UI or when you are formatting whatever is supposed to be printed?

You *can* [Cast or Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) an INT value into a VARCHAR using e.g. `CAST(@avg as VARCHAR)` and thereby making it legal to perform string concatenation using the `+` operator. This will of course also impact the return type of your sproc.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to string while printing

```
declare @avg int
set @avg = 80

select Convert(varchar(5),@avg) + '%'

or

print Convert(varchar(5),@avg) + '%'
```

I hope this help to u...

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @avg int
exec example @avg output
select cast(@avg as nvarchar(10))  + '%'
```